# How to test subscribe in jasmine /angular/ karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test for a component which has a method with subscribe and error handlers.
my `.ts` file has this

```
public viewDetails(orderNumber, orderType, orderCompany, businessUnitDesc): void {
    this.showingDetails = true;
    this.detailsLoading = true;
    this.spinnerMessage = 'Loading Details';
 
    const ordDet = {
        orderNumber,
        orderType,
        orderCompany
    };
 
    this.businessUnitDesc = businessUnitDesc;
 
    this.http.post<OrderDetailsResponse>(this.orderDetailsUrl, ordDet).subscribe(data => {
 
        this.detailJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

        this.orderDetails = data;
      
        this.freightHandlingCodeDesc = this.modeOfTrnDesc = this.routeCodeDesc = '';
        this.getDescForFreightHandlingCode(this.orderDetails.freightHandlingCode);
        this.getDescForModeOfTrnsCode(this.orderDetails.modeofTrn);
        this.getDescForRouteCode(this.orderDetails.routeCode);
 
        this.stopDetailsLoading();
        this.appInsightsService.logEvent('Order Details', {orderNumber});
    },
    error => {
       this.detailsLoading = false;
       this.appInsightsService.logException(error);
       this.authService.viewStandardErrorMessage();
    });
```

}

I have have tried to test for it in `.spec.ts` file like this:

```
it ('should view details', () => {
    component.viewDetails(1, 'a', 'b', 'c');
    expect(component.showingDetails).toBe(true);
    expect(component.detailsLoading).toBe(true);
    expect(component.spinnerMessage).toBe('Loading Details');
});
```

My test only test for the first part. How do I test for the rest of the function  including subscribe and errors?

Answer (score 3):

You can use fakeAsync as well as flush() and tick()

```
it ('should set detailJsonString to the results string', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockDataObj = getMockData();
    const httpSpy = TestBed.inject(HttpClient)
    spyOn(httpSpy, 'post').and.returnValue(of(mockDataObj))
   
    component.viewDetails(1, 'a', 'b', 'c');
    flush(); // clear out any pending tasks in queue including observable magic
    tick(); // simulate passage of time
    const expectedString = JSON.stringify(mockDataObj);
    expect(component.detailJsonString).toEqual(expectedString);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

All you seem to be missing is spying on the http request to mock the response.

```js
const httpSpy = TestBed.inject(HttpClient)
spyOn(httpSpy, 'post').and.returnValue(of(MOCKDATA_GOES_HERE))
// call your method that calls the http request
// do your stuff
```